# Can't Access JPanel's Public method/variable, and can't access from Jpanel other public method/variable

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel

```
package client;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class YootPanel extends JPanel
{

    private ImageIcon bgIcon;
    public JTextArea textBox;
    public ClientUI clientUI;
    public static final int HORSE_HEIGHT = 25;
    public static final int HORSE_WIDTH = 40;
    public int r1,r2,r3,r4;
    public int b1,b2,b3,b4;
    YootPanelPlot plot;

    public YootPanel(ClientUI clientUI)
    {
        super();    
        init_rest();
        init_bg();
            plot =  = new YootPanelPlot();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.clientUI = clientUI;
    }

    private void init_bg()
    {
        java.net.URL imgUrl = ClientUI.class.getResource("../images/images/background.png");
        bgIcon = new ImageIcon(imgUrl);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        try
        {
            g.drawImage(bgIcon.getImage(), -20, 0, null);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {


        set_Loc();


        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(plot.plot[0][r1], plot.plot[1][r1], HORSE_WIDTH, HORSE_HEIGHT);
        g.fillOval(plot.plot[0][r2], plot.plot[1][r2], HORSE_WIDTH, HORSE_HEIGHT);
        g.fillOval(plot.plot[0][r3], plot.plot[1][r3], HORSE_WIDTH, HORSE_HEIGHT);
        g.fillOval(plot.plot[0][r4], plot.plot[1][r4], HORSE_WIDTH, HORSE_HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(plot.plot[0][b1], plot.plot[1][b1], HORSE_WIDTH, HORSE_HEIGHT);
        g.fillOval(plot.plot[0][b2], plot.plot[1][b2], HORSE_WIDTH, HORSE_HEIGHT);
        g.fillOval(plot.plot[0][b3], plot.plot[1][b3], HORSE_WIDTH, HORSE_HEIGHT);
        g.fillOval(plot.plot[0][b4], plot.plot[1][b4], HORSE_WIDTH, HORSE_HEIGHT);
        System.err.println("Paint");
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

    }

private void init_rest()
{
        this.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Yoot Map"));
        this.setFocusable(false);
        this.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(670, 400));
        this.setName("map"); // NOI18N
        this.setOpaque(false);
        this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(630, 400));
        this.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(630, 400));
        this.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout yootMapLayout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(yootMapLayout);
        yootMapLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        yootMapLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING).add(0, 658, Short.MAX_VALUE));
yootMapLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        yootMapLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING).add(0, 442, Short.MAX_VALUE));
}

    public void set_Loc()
    {
        try
        {
            System.err.println("......"+clientUI.client.c2.blueHorseLocation[0]);
            r1 = clientUI.client.c2.getRed(0);
            r2 = clientUI.client.c2.getRed(1);
            r3 = clientUI.client.c2.getRed(2);
            r4 = clientUI.client.c2.getRed(3);
            b1 = clientUI.client.c2.blueHorseLocation[0];
            b2 = clientUI.client.c2.blueHorseLocation[1];
            b3 = clientUI.client.c2.blueHorseLocation[2];
            b4 = clientUI.client.c2.blueHorseLocation[3];
        } catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get updates for where to put draw the ovals.
However the last part's r1 = clientUI.client.c2.getRed(1); throws an NullPointerException

So I tried accessing this Classes public variables r1, r2 ... etc however, I couldn't reach these public variables either....

Is there a way I can modify these variables so that I cam move the ovals around as I get new coordinate updates?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: BTW - good call on fixing the formatting, but your code still has both a `paintComponent()` & `paint()` method. If you do not follow the advice offered, or request further clarification of the advice, what is the point of people offering any?

Comment: Thanks for your advice @AndrewThompson ! I found out that I was calling on this class in a very wrong way...
I did a 
JPanel yootMap = new YootPanel(clientUI); 
instead of a 
YootPanel yootMap = new YootPanel(clientUI);

Answer (score 1):

Don't use public variables.

Define methods to udate the values of any property that you want to change.

Also, custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method. You should not be overriding the paint() method.

Comment: I can't seem to access public methods either... For some reason my NetBeans IDE doesn't show them in the popup box, and If I manually write the public methods, I run into a error.

Comment: I really don't understand why the clientUI.client.c2.getRed(0); returns a NullPointerException.... They have already exist.... @camickr

Comment: I don't use IDE's to write code, so I don't know what your problem is. I would guess you should not be using YootPanelPlot plot = new YootPanelPlot(); in any paint() method. Also, I can't read your code because it is not formatted properly.

Comment: @camickr Okay I tried reformatting as much as I could. I moved the drawing of ovals to the paintComponent() method; however I still get the problem with the NullPointerException when I try to get the value clientUI.c2.blueHorseLocation[0];....

Comment: I tried calling clientUI.c2.blueHorseLocation[0] just before repaint(); from another class, and it returned the value of the blue Horse's Location; however I right afterwards when the repaint() is called, I get that NullPointerException...

Comment: @Heartinpiece: We'll have trouble guessing where your problem is without updated code. I suggest you create a very small program that demonstrates your problem, and that we can test and run ourselves, an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) as has been suggested above.

Comment: I was working on creating a SSCCE however, I found out that I was calling on this class in a wrong way.
JPanel yootMap = new YootPanel(clientUI); Wrong Object type! 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I was being stupid and did a wrong job when creating the object...
I should have used

```
YootPanel object = new YootPanel();
```

but I used

```
JPanel object = new YootPanel();
```

instead....
No wonder I couldn't access the methods that I created in the YootPanel class....

Thank you all for all your Answers!